# PLSQL functions in packages query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having a table named employees..i want to write two functions.1st function by using refcursor it want to fetch all the rows from employess table...and the result wil be shown through 2nd function.These two functions should be in one single package

Comment: by all means, go for it!

Comment: So, what's your question exactly? And what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, tell us what problems you've encountered, and perhaps someone can help - but until you put some effort in to doing the assignment on your own you can't expect us to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question shows very little industry or effort to work out a solution.

Start by reading the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_programs.htm) and it'll help you immensely.

As an example of what you want to achieve:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE ref_cur_package
AS
   FUNCTION get_emp
      RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;

   PROCEDURE show_emp;
END ref_cur_package;



CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY ref_cur_package
AS
   FUNCTION get_emp
      RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
   IS
      emp_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
   BEGIN
      OPEN emp_rc
       FOR SELECT *
             FROM emp;

      RETURN emp_rc;
   END get_emp;

   PROCEDURE show_emp
   IS
      emp_rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
      emp_row emp%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
      emp_rc := get_emp;

      LOOP
         FETCH emp_rc INTO emp_row;

         EXIT WHEN emp_rc%NOTFOUND;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Employee: '||emp_row.firstname||' '||emp_row.lastname);
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE emp_rc;
   END show_emp;
END ref_cur_package;
/
```

To see the output you'll need to set the [serveroutput on](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm).

You should also add an exception handler to force the closure of the ref cursor if there is a problem but I will leave that to you to research.